# Why without Consent AzureAD Application Refresh Token gets delivered

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Trying to get an access_token and refresh_token in a test-setup.
For this I am doing an oauth2 call with help of

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{ Tenant-ID }}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?......
```

and where the **response_type** is **code**
With help of the CODE the next all will be the TOKEN call

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{ Tenant-ID }}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Now when I only allow the Consent "User.Read" to be allowed and I put the Scope "offline_access" inside the request I am getting anyway the Refresh_Token delivered, even though it should not be allowed as the "offline_access" API permission is not configured/allowed.

But nevertheless getting:

```
"token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "profile openid email https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read",
    "expires_in": 4428,
    "ext_expires_in": 4428,
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJu..............",
    "refresh_token": "0.AUcAuGA_3_QwX0CgVgAhyncAz5epG.................."
}
```

From what I have read is, that we need to add and approve the consent for that.
Any idea why that is getting anyway delivered in the response?
Thanks.

After trying the reuquest:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{ Tenant-ID }}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

with the scope:

```
--data-urlencode 'scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read offline_access'
```

getting Access- and Refresh Token (both)

Answer (score 0):

I created an Azure AD application and granted API permissions:

[image]

I used the below **authorize** endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=profile openid email https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
&state=12345
```

[image]

Now, when I tried to generate the tokens **only access and ID tokens got generated**:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:profile openid email https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

> **Why without Consent AzureAD Application Refresh Token gets delivered**

- If the refresh token is generated without passing or granting `offline_access` scope then the user might have consented previously to the `offline_access` scope.
- Hence check the user consent from a Previous Interaction.
  and the scope is not explicitly granted to the Azure AD application.
- If still the issue persists, create a new Azure AD application and try generating the tokens without granting and passing `offline_access` scope.